# Format for future date

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using a macro to send reports Monday to Friday.

```
.Subject = "Report For - " & Format(Now + 1, "Long Date")
```

How do I if I am sending the report on Friday which is for Monday?

e.g:
When I send the Report on Friday which is For Monday I get the date Report for - Saturday, April 18, 2015

Comment: i got confused to be honest. do u mean the Friday before the Monday or the Friday after the Monday :P Please use an example with dates to get the idea clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will pick the next day for Sunday-Thursday

It will pick Monday for Friday and Saturday

```
Dim strIn As String
Select Case Weekday(Now)
Case 1 To 5
    strIn = "Report For - " & Format(Now + 1, "Long Date")
Case Else
    strIn = "Report For - " & Format(Now + (9 - Weekday(Now)), "Long Date")
End Select
```